# Reading Third Array from JSON in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been handed a c# website to bring to completion. I have limited knowledge of C# so its a learning curve and I apologise if some of my terminology is off.

The site pulls a JSON output via an async task on another project, uses Newtonsoft to serialize and then proceeds to declare the values in classes. I am trying to add a value into a variable from a third tier of arrays in the JSON but I am unable to then output this into the desired location.

Here is an example of a JSON output that is received by the code

```
"code": "ILM5AM",
"title": "ILM Level 5 Award in Leadership & Management",
"items": [
    {
        "item": {
            "id": 18
                },
      "id": 326
    }
],
"days": 6,
"id": 302,
"categories": [
    {
        "children": [],
    "id": 55,
    "name": "Leadership and Management"
    }
```

I want to extract the Items.Item.Id value and use to do the following in an import project newPage.MappedItemId = courseSummary.StandardItem.Id;

Here is the code I have so far

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using TSW.Model.Interfaces;

namespace TSW.Model.DTO
{
    public class Course : IEntity
    {
        public Course()
        {
           _additionalData = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();

    }

    [JsonExtensionData(WriteData = false)]
    private IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public double? Days { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public Item StandardItem { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
       if (_additionalData.ContainsKey("items"))
        {
            StandardItem = new Item();
            StandardItem.Id = _additionalData["items"][0]["item"][0]["id"].ToObject<int>();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Finally this is the Item.cs project that captures the Item related values

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using TSW.Model.Interfaces;

namespace TSW.Model.DTO
{
    public class Item : IEntity
    {
        public List<Price> Prices { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: That is not valid JSON for a start...

Comment: Paul, what error are you getting?

Comment: The JSON output is a sample from a call that is just made in a browser as I was avoiding large bit of JSON. This sample hasn’t gone through a serialiser but I know the serialiser is working as the other values are working fine. The error I am getting is that the value of StandardItem is 0 so it’s not finding the value from [“items”][“item”][“id”] @derloopkat